# ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled

Tags: drivers, server, apt, package-management

```
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

When I try to use

```
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

to reinstall it repeats the error

```
Package: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Versions: 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
Reverse Depends: gnumeric,ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Dependencies: 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 - 
Provides: 3.4+nmu1ubuntu2 -
Reverse Provides: –
```

I have the multiverse repository enabled.

Comment: the command `apt-cache showpkg ttf-mscorefonts-installer` tells me the package can be found in the 'multiverse' repo. for my 16.04 box, so do you have multiverse enabled?

Comment: Please edit the question instead of burying information in the comments. Please also use the formatting tools to make output easier to grok.

Answer (score 0):

Okay . you can change this topic to [Solved] i knew where is the problem , i had a problem with apt-get update that stucks at Zero, one of the sources was using https instead of http i removed this source and updated the apt-get and all worked fine , thanks !